# Firebase and React Object is possibly 'null'. TS2531

Tags: typescript, firebase, null, firebase-authentication

I'm developing an app in react and firebase , when I'm trying to write in the database shows me this error, I don't know why:

Object is possibly 'null'.  TS2531
and it marks this code

```
export async function registerUser(email: string, password: string, name:string, lastname: string, phoneNumber: string){
    firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password).then(cred => {
        return db.collection('users').doc(cred.user.uid).set({
                                          ^
            'name': name,
            'lastname': lastname,
            'phone-number': phoneNumber
        })
    }).then(() => {
        redirectTo('/login')
    })
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see from the API documentation for [createUserWithEmailAndPassword](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#createuserwithemailandpassword), `cred` is a [UserCredential](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth#usercredential) object.  The doc for that suggests that its `user` property can be null.  Whether or not it can *ever* be null in this context is not relevant - TypeScript is suggesting that you should check it anyway in order to avoid a possible crash.  So, just do so:

```
firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password).then(cred => {
    const user = cred.user
    if (user) {
        // use user safely here
    }
})
```

Comment: Great!  On Stack Overflow, it's customary to upvote and accept helpful answers using the buttons on the left of the answer.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation :( sorry! I'm new here

Comment: Everyone should be able to accept an answer as correct on their own question.  It's the checkmark to the left.

Comment: Oh, I forgot. I thought that you mean the up arrow button